# She tangled up the sheet on the bed VS. She tangled up the sheets on the bed

Tags: idiomatic-language

> She tangled up the sheet on the bed. (the sheet is singular)

VS.

> She tangled up the sheets on the bed. (while the sheets are plural)

Which one is more idiomatic?

Comment: That depends (entirely) on whether she tangled up just the top sheet or the bottom sheet as well!

Comment: And raises a strange little cultural point...In the UK, beds are made with one sheet and you sleep on it.  In the US, beds are made with two and you sleep between them.

Comment: @JamesK - I think that's because (perhaps?) the duvet, now practically universal in the UK, requires but one sheet, under the sleeper, tucked tightly around the mattress. I think duvets are not as popular in the US? I remember up to the 1980s using the two-sheet plus blanket, quilt, etc arrangement. Brits rather suspiciously called duvets 'continental quilts' when I was young.

Comment: @JamesK - I'll try to keep this decent. I am trying to imagine the sort of gyrations the lady performed to tangle up the sheets, just while occupying the bed, since I think of tangling two or more things, or something with itself, e.g. fishing line, as so thoroughly intertwining them that it is hard (or at least tedious) to separate them again, like string in a drawer or the wires behind my computer. To tangle sheets might call for some vigorous nocturnal exercise, if I can put it that way.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey if I remember correctly duvet already had a meaning, it was a quilted top layer, that was only warm enough for use in high summer, so we needed a new name to show you had the exciting new item, and were not simply shivering mid winter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(just summarising comment)

You can use the semantically correct form of the noun. If there are two sheets (as is common in the USA) use "sheets"

If there is one sheet that is tangled (as is common in the UK) use "sheet"

If you are using "sheets" to mean "bedding in general" (and implicitly including blankets, duvets, quilts etc).  That is you are not speaking in a precise way but using "sheets" metonymically, then use the plural.

I suspect that the context is that the sheet(s) blankets etc became disturbed following some "vigorous nocturnal exercise" and so the precise sense of "sheet" isn't being used, and nor is the precise sense of "tangled". As this is figurative use of language, "sheets" is quite acceptable.

Comment: I must add that when I have been feverish I have awoken to find the sheet somewhat disturbed, so maybe I let my imagination get the better of me in my comment above.

Comment: I am trying (seriously, now) to imagine how a sheet might get 'tangled'. Wrinkled, creased, even rucked up, yes, but _tangled_?

Comment: but if you are using it to mean bedding in general wouldn't it be better simply to say "bedding"

Comment: She had tangled up the sheets on the bed as she lay tossing and turning.